# The designer in Visual Studio will not set label text to value

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2022, designer

My program will not show the values of, hit points, experience, level, and gold. I have labels show the amount of each one as seen here.

```
public Label lblHitPoints;
public Label lblExperience;
public Label lblLevel;
public Label lblGold;
```

I then have declared the amounts of each of these with this piece of code:

```
{
    CurrentHitPoints = 10,
    MaximumHitPoints = 10,
    Gold = 20,
    ExperiencePoints = 0,
    Level = 1,
};

lblHitPoints.Text = _player.CurrentHitPoints.ToString();
lblGold.Text = _player.Gold.ToString();
lblExperience.Text = _player.ExperiencePoints.ToString();
lblLevel.Text = _player.Level.ToString();
```

This will still not show on the designer even with this.

I have tried different ways of formatting this but they do not seem to fit and I can't think of anything else.
its still not working despite errors but I do have this
https://github.com/kingsley700/super-adventure

Comment: Which VS Designer? WinForms? Where does the code you show run. Are you saying that you can't see the values at design-time or at run-time?

Comment: Please show the entire code that run this method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your declaring the label variables yourself in the `Form` and not using the designer drag and drop feature, then you need to add these labels by the `form_name.Controls.Add(label_Name)` and set their location on the Form manually. It is because when using the toolbox to add the labels on the designer it will automatically generate the code required the display it on the Form.

Player class:

```
public class Player
{
    public int CurrentHitPoints;
    public int MaximumHitPoints;
    public int Gold;
    public int ExperiencePoints;
    public int Level;
}
```

Form to display the labels:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Label lblHitPoints = new Label();
    public Label lblExperience = new Label();
    public Label lblLevel = new Label();
    public Label lblGold = new Label();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Controls.Add(lblExperience);
        this.Controls.Add(lblGold);
        this.Controls.Add(lblHitPoints);
        this.Controls.Add(lblLevel);

        lblExperience.Top = 0;
        lblGold.Top = 20;
        lblHitPoints.Top = 40;
        lblLevel.Top = 60;

        Player _player = new Player{ 
            CurrentHitPoints = 10,
            MaximumHitPoints = 10,
            Gold = 20,
            ExperiencePoints = 0,
            Level = 1
         };

        lblHitPoints.Text = _player.CurrentHitPoints.ToString();
        lblGold.Text = _player.Gold.ToString();
        lblExperience.Text = _player.ExperiencePoints.ToString();
        lblLevel.Text = _player.Level.ToString();
    }
}
```